# TFS 2010 abort servicing activity

Tags: sql-server-2008, collections, default, sql-server-2008-r2

At the start of the year I pushed to setting up TFS for a more structured approach to things (before, everyone would change things as they went, obviously A Bad Thing). I set up a very basic single server TFS 2010 installation. The TFS databases resided on one of our Dev servers (SQL 2008).

Everything went well until:
We uninstalled SQL 2008, installed SQL 2008 R2 and reattached the databases. Since then TFS has been impossible:

- The clients (SQL Mgt Studio and VS2008/2010) could no longer connect (error 404 not found)
- http://localhost:8080/tfs/ gave:
  "Team Foundation services are not available from the server.
  Technical information (for administrator):
  The request could not be processed because the application is not configured correctly. No service host is available for the request."
- Team Foundation Admin Console finds the collections, everything SEEMS ok.

In an effort to jumpstart things:

- I restarted the website and it's application pool
- I rebooted the server

No effect.

Then I stopped the collection (that worked) to re-enter the database information, save it and start the collection again. However, it kept hanging on the save. I tried to detach the collection, but that didn't do anything. So now I have a stopped collection with the following activities:

- Prepare Collection (Success)
- Create Collection (Success)
- Servicing Collection (Queued)
- Detach Collection (Queued) (3 times, since I tried this a couple of time)

and nothing is budging.

I have all source in my local folder, so in extremis I can delete and uninstall the whole thing and start over, but... I rather not.

Any way to unblock this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, This was solved by re-adding the TFS machine account to the new SQL Server installation using

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_grantlogin @loginame = N'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'
```

as detailed [here](http://www.sqldev.org/getting-started-with-sql-server/how-to-add-computer-account-in-sql-2005-98197.shtml). From then on all tasks proceeded as they should..
What tipped me off was the following error in the Application Log:

> TF53010: The following error has
>   occurred in a Team Foundation
>   component or extension: Date (UTC):
>   22/06/2011 18:07:22 Machine: AZT-TS-02
>   Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe
>   Assembly:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a;
>   v2.0.50727 Service Host:  Process
>   Details:   Process Name: TFSJobAgent
>   Process Id: 2980   Thread Id: 3804
>   Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
>   SERVICE
>
> Detailed Message: There was an error
>   during job agent execution. The
>   operation will be retried. Similar
>   errors in the next five minutes may
>   not be logged. Exception Message:
>   TF246017: Team Foundation Server could
>   not connect to the database. Verify
>   that the server that is hosting the
>   database is operational, and that
>   network problems are not blocking
>   communication with the server. (type
>   DatabaseConnectionException)

Answer (score 1):

Good times,

Try running the following command:

TFSConfig registerDB /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration /SQLInstance:SERVERNAME /Continue

RegisterDB updates the name of the server that hosts the configuration database and in this case should resolve your DB issues.  Another command you could try is [RemapDBs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349262.aspx).

Make sure you "Run As Admin" for these commands or they of course will not work.

I am guessing what is going on is attaching isn't going to be enough because TFS internal mappings no longer understands where your SQL Server db is.

Hope that helps.